# Why saving managed object context changes isDeleted value?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, managedobjectcontext

I am writing an iOS app using SwiftUI and Core Data. I am very new to Core Data and try to understand something:

Why **try self.moc.save()** changes **self.item.isDeleted** from **true** to **false**?
It happens after I delete a Core Data object (isDeleted changes to true), but later saving managed object context changes it to false. Why is that?

Here is an example:

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Item>
    var items: FetchedResults<Item> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(item: item)) {
                        Text("\(item.name ?? "default item name")")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Items")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: {
                    for number in 1...3 {
                        let item = Item(context: self.moc)
                        item.date = Date()
                        item.name = "Item \(number)"
                        
                        do {
                            try self.moc.save()
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Add 3 items")
                }
            )
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true)
        ])
    }
}
```

**DetailsView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("\(item.name ?? "default item name")")
        }
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.moc.delete(self.item)
                print(self.item.isDeleted)

                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                print(self.item.isDeleted)
                
                do {
                    try self.moc.save()
                    print(self.item.isDeleted)
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }) {
                Text("Delete")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        )
        .onDisappear {
            print(self.item.isDeleted)
            if !self.item.isDeleted {
                print(self.item.isDeleted)
                self.item.name = "new name"
                print(self.item.isDeleted)
                do {
                    try self.moc.save()
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

**What I expected will happen:**

1. **self.moc.delete(self.item)** will delete an object and mark **self.item.isDeleted** as true.
2. **try self.moc.save** will save moc
3. **if !self.item.isDeleted** will prevent code execution if item is deleted (without this, I was getting an error: Mutating a managed object (...) after it has been removed)

It didn't work. I have added **print(self.item.isDeleted)** on few lines and breakpoints on those lines to check what exactly happens.

**What happened is this:**

1. **self.moc.delete(self.item)** deleted an object and marked **self.item.isDeleted** as true.
2. **try self.moc.save** saved moc and...
3. **self.item.isDeleted** changed to be false
4. **if !self.item.isDeleted** didn't prevent code execution, because isDeleted was false at this point.

Is it a bug? Or I don't understand the life cycle of Core Data objects and isDeleted changes as it should?

Comment: After deleting a CoreData entity, you should not change it anyway. What you can do, is that you store a own value for every entity isDeleted. When you want to remove a item, you just change that bool to true. Then you can use that everywhere in your View/ FetchRequest. You have to be careful as the entity is not getting deleted than. You could remove objects with isDeleted after a while.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it in a similar way. I added `@State private var itemExists = true` to the DetailsView and I am changing its value after deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why try self.moc.save() changes self.item.isDeleted from true to
> false? It happens after I delete a Core Data object (isDeleted changes
> to true), but later saving managed object context changes it to false.
> Why is that?

It behaves as documented - returns *true* **before** save, and not in other cases

Here is snapshot of Apple documentation for `NSManagedObject`:

> Summary
>
> A Boolean value that indicates **whether the managed object will be**
> **deleted** during the next save. Declaration
>
> *var isDeleted: Bool { get } Discussion*
>
> true if Core Data will ask the persistent store to delete the object
> during the next save operation, otherwise false. It may return false
> at other times, particularly after the object has been deleted. The
> immediacy with which it will stop returning true depends on where the
> object is in the process of being deleted. If the receiver is a fault,
> accessing this property does not cause it to fire.